# after addpath still can not recognize function

Tags: matlab

I am brand new to matlab, trying to get a github code working. The code requires code from another github library, which I cloned. And I added the path to the referenced code in addpath('/home/me/ref_lib'). But it still bombs on the line where it calls a function

Unrecognized function or variable xxxx.

how can diagnose this? Can I check which functions are available on the path?

Comment: Try `what /home/me/ref_lib` to see what functions exist in that directory. You might have downloaded sources to MEX-files, which need to be compiled first. Make sure to follow any installation instructions. For any more help you’ll have to include a lot more information and a [mre].

Comment: Providing some files would be helpful. In any case, first check at what line this error is coming. Then check that if the function or variable that is being called in that line is a function in the code that you got it from github or is it a function provided by a MATLAB toolbox. If the function is provided by a MATLAB toolbox, then probably you do not have that toolbox or you are running on an old MATLAB where this new function is not available. Makes sense?

Comment: yes, that was it. the *.c file was compiled for mac, not for linux. Thank you!